# SQL query to get distinct elements of maximum values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following tables

```
|Id| Title  |
|1 |Lesson 1|
|2 |Lesson 2|
|3 |Lesson 3|
|4 |Lesson 4|
|5 |Lesson 5|
|6 |Lesson 6|

|Id|Lesson|Score|
|1 |  2   | 75  |
|2 |  3   | 30  |
|3 |  3   | 90  |
```

I want to get distinct lessons but with the maximum value only, so the result would be:

```
|Lesson|Score|
|  2   | 75  |
|  3   | 90  |
```

So in the following query, where do I put DISTINCT and MAX to achieve such result?

```
SELECT LessonConclusionData.Lesson, LessonConclusionData.Score
FROM LessonConclusionData INNER JOIN Lessons ON LessonConclusionData.Lesson = Lessons.Id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by Lesson and get MAX(Score).

```
SELECT LessonConclusionData.Lesson, MAX(LessonConclusionData.Score) as MaxScore
FROM LessonConclusionData 
     INNER JOIN Lessons ON LessonConclusionData.Lesson = Lessons.Id
GROUP BY LessonConclusionData.Lesson;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID,MAX(SCORE)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY ID`
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming SQL Server version >= 2005, this code (which uses a Common Table Expression) will produce the desired result:

```
; with x as (
select Lesson, max(Score) Score
from LessonConclusionData
group by Lesson
)
select y.* from x join LessonConclusionData y on x.Lesson = y.Lesson and x.Score = y.Score
order by y.Lesson
```

Only if you need to display the lesson's name should you join with the Lessons table as in:

```
; with x as (
select Lesson, max(Score) Score
from LessonConclusionData
group by Lesson
)
select y.*, Lessons.Title from x join LessonConclusionData y on x.Lesson = y.Lesson and x.Score = y.Score
right join Lessons on x.Lesson = Lessons.Id
order by y.Lesson
```

where I chose RIGHT JOIN instead to return results for all lessons, even for those where no LessonConclusionData exists. If you want to return only those lessons for which details exist use INNER JOIN instead.

Comment: Apparently the question was edited, and the Lessons.Id column is not part of the result anymore!